# fullName is missing in Custom field in Metadata api v29.0

Tags: metadata-api, wsdl2apex, wsdl

i downloaded a metadata wsdl.created apex class MetadataSerbvice.i wirte a simple code

```
MetadataService.CustomField cf = new MetadataService.CustomField();
cf.fullName ="Asset.ProductLine__c";
```

but its giving me error variable fullName is not defined and there is no field named as fullName in CustomField class .my custom field class is

```
public class CustomField {
    public Boolean caseSensitive;
    public String customDataType;
    public String defaultValue;
    public String deleteConstraint;
    public Boolean deprecated;
    public String description;
    public String displayFormat;
    public Boolean escapeMarkup;
    public String externalDeveloperName;
    public Boolean externalId;
    public String formula;
    public String formulaTreatBlanksAs;
    public String inlineHelpText;
    public Boolean isFilteringDisabled;
    public Boolean isNameField;
    public Boolean isSortingDisabled;
    public String label;
    public Integer length;
    public String maskChar;
    public String maskType;
    public MetadataService.Picklist picklist;
    public Boolean populateExistingRows;
    public Integer precision;
    public String referenceTo;
    public String relationshipLabel;
    public String relationshipName;
    public Integer relationshipOrder;
    public Boolean reparentableMasterDetail;
    public Boolean required;
    public Boolean restrictedAdminField;
    public Integer scale;
    public Integer startingNumber;
    public Boolean stripMarkup;
    public String summarizedField;
    public MetadataService.FilterItem[] summaryFilterItems;
    public String summaryForeignKey;
    public String summaryOperation;
    public Boolean trackFeedHistory;
    public Boolean trackHistory;
    public Boolean trackTrending;
    public String type_x;
    public Boolean unique;
    public Integer visibleLines;
    public Boolean writeRequiresMasterRead;
    private String[] caseSensitive_type_info = new String[]{'caseSensitive','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] customDataType_type_info = new String[]{'customDataType','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] defaultValue_type_info = new String[]{'defaultValue','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] deleteConstraint_type_info = new String[]{'deleteConstraint','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] deprecated_type_info = new String[]{'deprecated','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] displayFormat_type_info = new String[]{'displayFormat','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] escapeMarkup_type_info = new String[]{'escapeMarkup','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] externalDeveloperName_type_info = new String[]{'externalDeveloperName','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] externalId_type_info = new String[]{'externalId','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] formula_type_info = new String[]{'formula','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] formulaTreatBlanksAs_type_info = new String[]{'formulaTreatBlanksAs','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] inlineHelpText_type_info = new String[]{'inlineHelpText','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] isFilteringDisabled_type_info = new String[]{'isFilteringDisabled','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] isNameField_type_info = new String[]{'isNameField','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] isSortingDisabled_type_info = new String[]{'isSortingDisabled','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] label_type_info = new String[]{'label','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] length_type_info = new String[]{'length','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] maskChar_type_info = new String[]{'maskChar','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] maskType_type_info = new String[]{'maskType','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] picklist_type_info = new String[]{'picklist','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] populateExistingRows_type_info = new String[]{'populateExistingRows','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] precision_type_info = new String[]{'precision','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] referenceTo_type_info = new String[]{'referenceTo','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] relationshipLabel_type_info = new String[]{'relationshipLabel','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] relationshipName_type_info = new String[]{'relationshipName','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] relationshipOrder_type_info = new String[]{'relationshipOrder','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] reparentableMasterDetail_type_info = new String[]{'reparentableMasterDetail','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] required_type_info = new String[]{'required','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] restrictedAdminField_type_info = new String[]{'restrictedAdminField','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] scale_type_info = new String[]{'scale','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] startingNumber_type_info = new String[]{'startingNumber','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] stripMarkup_type_info = new String[]{'stripMarkup','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] summarizedField_type_info = new String[]{'summarizedField','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] summaryFilterItems_type_info = new String[]{'summaryFilterItems','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] summaryForeignKey_type_info = new String[]{'summaryForeignKey','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] summaryOperation_type_info = new String[]{'summaryOperation','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] trackFeedHistory_type_info = new String[]{'trackFeedHistory','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] trackHistory_type_info = new String[]{'trackHistory','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] trackTrending_type_info = new String[]{'trackTrending','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] type_x_type_info = new String[]{'type','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] unique_type_info = new String[]{'unique','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] visibleLines_type_info = new String[]{'visibleLines','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] writeRequiresMasterRead_type_info = new String[]{'writeRequiresMasterRead','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'caseSensitive','customDataType','defaultValue','deleteConstraint','deprecated','description','displayFormat','escapeMarkup','externalDeveloperName','externalId','formula','formulaTreatBlanksAs','inlineHelpText','isFilteringDisabled','isNameField','isSortingDisabled','label','length','maskChar','maskType','picklist','populateExistingRows','precision','referenceTo','relationshipLabel','relationshipName','relationshipOrder','reparentableMasterDetail','required','restrictedAdminField','scale','startingNumber','stripMarkup','summarizedField','summaryFilterItems','summaryForeignKey','summaryOperation','trackFeedHistory','trackHistory','trackTrending','type_x','unique','visibleLines','writeRequiresMasterRead'};
}
```

how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: one solution is adding extends Metadata but why my apex is not automatically inherited from metadata ??

Comment: using extend its giving me error Description Resource Path Location Type
Save error: MetadataService.CustomField: Non-virtual and non-abstract type cannot be extended

Comment: Yes see the steps below you need to make the Metadata class 'virtual'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **WSDL2Apex** tool does not support the **xsd:extension** concept, so types such as **CustomField** that extend from the **Metadata** type (which provides the fullName) in the XML Schema do not reflect this relationship in the generated Apex code. You need to manually edit the generated Apex code afterwards. The **full steps** for preparing a Metadata API generated Apex class are described [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi#how-to-create-your-own-metadataservicecls), replicated below. If you want to copy a version of **CustomField** class with this already applied see [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L1038).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The Salesforce Metadata API is backwards compatible, meaning you can use the earlier v28.0 API with the current platform release. Unless you have a specific reason to want the v29.0 API version, you can simply download a [MetadataService.cls](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) and [MetadataServiceTest.cls](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceTest.cls) pre-built and ready to go! If you need the v29.0 version features for some reason, you can follow the steps below or wait for the author of the library to update the above classes in the coming week or so.

```
- Generating a valid Apex MetadataService class
      - Edit the WSDL
           - Change the Port name from 'Metadata' to 'MetadataPort'
           - As of Summer'13 (API 28) there was a small bug in the CustomField type definition, change the 'type' element definition to include a minOccurs="0" atttribute, as per the other elements in this type.
      - Attempt to generate Apex from this WSDL
           - Give it a better name if you want when prompted, e.g. MetadataService
           - In earlier platform releases this would error, as update and delete are reserved words.
           - It seems this has now been fixed and as of Summer'13 the Metadata API WSDL generates without errors!
      - Open Eclipse (or your favourite editor)
           - Open the class
           - To be compatible with the samples here, edit the method name update_x to updateMetadata
           - To be compatible with the samples here, edit the method name delete_x to deleteMetadata
           - To be compatible with the samples here, edit the method name retrieve_x to retrieve
           - Save the class
      - Update the MetadataServiceTest class
           - Observe the uncovered items (new metadata operations, types added since last release)          
           - Add new code to cover operations and types
           - See this for guidelines http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/05/11/code-coverage-for-wsdl2apex-generated-classes
 - Making further edits to the Apex code
      - Modify the end point to be dynamic
           - public String endpoint_x = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/28.0';
      - Make 'Metadata' inner class 'virtual'
      - Make 'MetadataWithContent' inner class 'virtual'
      - Review WSDL for types that extend 'tns:Metadata' and update related Apex classes to also extend Metadata
      - Review WSDL for types that extend 'tns:MetadataWithContent' and update related Apex classes to also extend MetadataWithContent
      - Apply the following to each class that extends Metadata, e.g. for CustomObject
           Add the following at the top of the class
                public String type = 'CustomObject';
                public String fullName;
           Add the following at the top of the private static members
                private String[] type_att_info = new String[]{'xsi:type'};
                private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
           Add 'fullName' as the first item in the field_order_type_info String array, e.g.
                private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName', 'actionOverrides' …. 'webLinks'};
      - Apply the following to each class that extends MetadataWithContent, e.g. for ApexPage
           Add the following after 'fullName'
                public String content;
           Add the following after 'fullName_type_info'
                private String[] content_type_info = new String[]{'content','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','base64Binary','0','1','false'};
           Add 'content' after 'fullName' in the field_order_type_info String array, e.g.
                private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName', 'content', 'apiVersion','description','label','packageVersions'};
```